# Limited to 1024 file descriptors [relates to ulimit -n]

Tags: limits

I have a problem to setup shoutcastv2 for more than 1000 listeners. I always get the message as follows from shoutcast log. With shoutcast v1, I don´t have this problem.

```
INFO    [MAIN] Limited to 1024 file descriptors [relates to ulimit -n]
```

All files are correctly configured.

```
/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf 
/etc/security/limits.conf
```

See server ouput:

```
[root@live ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 96349
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 65535


cat /etc/security/limits.conf
*          soft     nproc          65535
*          hard     nproc          65535
*          soft     nofile         65535
*          hard     nofile         65535
```

Can any know about?

Thanks you.

Comment: Which distro are you running? Are you on `systemd` already?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running the shoutcastv2 process as 'root' user. If that is the case, you need to change the limits.conf and specify 'root' instead of 'wildcard'.

`man limits.conf`

```
NOTE: group and wildcard limits are not applied to the root user.
To set a limit for the root user, this field must contain the
literal username root.
```